# How to number each step of a solution in a visually appealing manner?

Tags: formatting, arrays

I am seeking assistance with formatting my solution. Specifically, I am looking for a way to number each step of the solution without using the format "Step 1:", "Step 2:", and so on. I am hoping to find a more visually appealing way to number each step.

Additionally, I would appreciate any help with formatting the solution neatly on Overleaf. If anyone has the skills to help me with these issues, please let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}    
\section{Task}
    1. Calculate the inverse of the matrix
    
    \[
    B=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
    0 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 4 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    \subsection{Solution}
    Gauss-Jordan elimination can be used to compute the inverse of the matrix $B$ . We start by augmenting the matrix B with an identity matrix to the right of the matrix $B$, so that we get it in the form $\left[B | I\right]$:
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    Step 1: Swap rows 1 and 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    Step 2: Divide row 1 by 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    Step 3: Divide row 2 by 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    Step 4: Multiply row 1 by 3 and subtract 3*row 1 from row 3
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    Step 5: Add row 3 with row 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    Step 6: Add $-2\cdot$ row 2 to row 1
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 0 & -3 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    Step 7: $R_3' = 5/2 \cdot R_3$
    
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 0 & -3 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
    Step 8: $R_1' = 3R_3+R_1$ and $R_2' = -1.5\cdot R_3 + R_2$
    
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{13}{10} & \frac{6}{5} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{9}{10} & -\frac{3}{5} \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
    We now have the matrix in reduced stair step form, which means we have found its inverse. Thus is
    
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{13}{10} & \frac{6}{5} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{9}{10} & -\frac{3}{5} \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, did you try to copy your code as posted here and compile it?  It doesn‘t, right? Please correct (and provide what‘s relevant AND missing). Will simplify helping considerably. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information about your problem, First, extend your code fragment to complete small document, that we can see  which documentclass you use, second use only LaTeX syntax . instead of `$$` use  `\[` and `\]`., third, this seems to be very opinion based question ...

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your response. I apologize if my previous message was unclear. While changing from the outdated $$ delimiter to the recommended 
 delimiter was one part of my question, I was also hoping for assistance with formatting equations and incorporating graphics into my document. Additionally, I understand that some aspects of document formatting can be subjective, but I was hoping for guidance on best practices or common conventions.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you for your response. Yes, I have made corrections to my original post by adding the missing code, including the necessary \begin{document} command and other relevant information. I apologize for any confusion my incomplete post may have caused, and I appreciate your suggestion to provide all relevant information to simplify the process of receiving help. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to make my question clearer. Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

- not really an answer ...
- it seems that you may try to use `exam` documentclass which probably is more appropriate for your purposes
- but design of your document is up to you
- an example of possible document design, where is introduced `enumitem` package for your steps, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{Task}
Calculate the inverse of the matrix
    \[
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 0 \\
3 & 5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
    \]
\subsection*{Solution}
Gauss-Jordan elimination can be used to compute the inverse of the matrix $B$. We start by augmenting the matrix B with an identity matrix to the right of the matrix $B$, so that we get it in the form $\left[B | I\right]$:
    \[
\left[\begin{array}{lll|lll}
0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
    \]
To the solution then yield the following steps:
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item   Swap rows 1 and 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
    2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\item   Divide row 1 by 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|rrr}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\item   Divide row 2 by 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\item   Multiply row 1 by 3 and subtract 3*row 1 from row 3
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\item   Add row 3 with row 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\item   Add $-2\cdot$ row 2 to row 1
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 0 & -3 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\item   $R_3' = 5/2 \cdot R_3$
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 0 & -3 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\item   $R_1' = 3R_3+R_1$ and $R_2' = -1.5\cdot R_3 + R_2$
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|rrr}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{13}{10} & \frac{6}{5} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{9}{10} & -\frac{3}{5} \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
We now have the matrix in reduced stair step form, which means we have found its inverse. Thus is
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{lll|rrr}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{13}{10} & \frac{6}{5} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{9}{10} & -\frac{3}{5} \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could load the `enumitem` package and use its machinery to create an enumerated list whose items start with the word "Step".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{stepenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[stepenum]{label={Step \arabic*.},wide=0pt}

\begin{document}    

\section{Task}

1. Calculate the inverse of the matrix
    \[
    B=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 4 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \]
    
\subsection{Solution}
Gauss-Jordan elimination can be used to compute the inverse of the matrix $B$. We start by augmenting the matrix $B$ with an identity matrix to the right of the matrix $B$, so that we get it in the form $[B \mid I]$:
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
   
\begin{stepenum}
\item Swap rows 1 and 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
\item Divide row 1 by 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
\item Divide row 2 by 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
\item Multiply row 1 by 3 and subtract 3*row 1 from row 3
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
\item Add row 3 with row 2
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\[\jot]
    0 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
\item Add $-2\cdot$ row 2 to row 1
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 0 & -3 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\[\jot]
    0 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
\item $R_3' = 5/2 \cdot R_3$ 
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 0 & -3 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\[\jot]
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
    
\item $R_1' = 3R_3+R_1$ and $R_2' = -1.5\cdot R_3 + R_2$
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{13}{10} & \frac{6}{5} \\[\jot]
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{9}{10} & -\frac{3}{5} \\[\jot]
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\end{stepenum}

We now have the matrix in reduced stair step form, which means we have found its inverse. Thus is
    \[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr|rrr@{}}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{13}{10} & \frac{6}{5} \\[\jot]
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{9}{10} & -\frac{3}{5} \\[\jot]
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
    \end{array}\right]
    \]

\end{document}
```